# Select query by comparing 2 table values

Tags: mysql, select

i have 2 tables (tbl_news and tbl_news_category)
tbl_news_category table is

```
cat_id  cat_name   general
1       name1       1
2       name2       1
3       name3       0
4       name4       1
5       name5       0
```

tbl_news table is

```
id    cat_id    title     news_isimage
1       2       title1      1
2       5       title2      0
3       1       title2      1
4       3       title2      1
5       2       title2      1
6       5       title2      1
7       4       title2      1
8       5       title2      1
```

i want to get 5 random items from tbl_news which general value should be 1
i tried below code and its not working

```
SELECT 
    d.*
FROM
    tbl_news d,
    tbl_news_category p
WHERE
    p.general = 1 AND d.news_isimage = 0
        AND d.cat_id > 3
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 5
```

but its giving news item with cat_id with general = 0

Comment: **Where's PHP?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a proper join of the tables:

```
select n.* 
from tbl_news n inner join tbl_news_category c
on c.cat_id = n.cat_id
where c.general = 1
order by rand() limit 5
```

You have also in your code the conditions:

```
news_isimage = 0 AND cat_id > 3
```

If you need them you can add them to the WHERE clause:

```
WHERE c.general = 1 AND n.news_isimage = 0 AND c.cat_id > 3
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no data for your query available.

But do an INNER JOIN

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tbl_news (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `cat_id` INTEGER,
>   `title` VARCHAR(6),
>   `news_isimage` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO tbl_news
>   (`id`, `cat_id`, `title`, `news_isimage`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '2', 'title1', '1'),
>   ('2', '5', 'title2', '0'),
>   ('3', '1', 'title2', '1'),
>   ('4', '3', 'title2', '1'),
>   ('5', '2', 'title2', '1'),
>   ('6', '5', 'title2', '1'),
>   ('7', '4', 'title2', '1'),
>   ('8', '5', 'title2', '1');
>
> CREATE TABLE tbl_news_category (
>   `cat_id` INTEGER,
>   `cat_name` VARCHAR(5),
>   `general` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO tbl_news_category
>   (`cat_id`, `cat_name`, `general`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'name1', '1'),
>   ('2', 'name2', '1'),
>   ('3', 'name3', '0'),
>   ('4', 'name4', '1'),
>   ('5', 'name5', '0');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>     tn.title
>     , tn.news_isimage
>     ,tnc.cat_name
> FROM tbl_news tn INNER JOIN tbl_news_category tnc ON tn.cat_id = tnc.cat_id 
> WHERE
>     tnc.general = 1 
>     AND tn.news_isimage = 0
>     AND tnc.cat_id > 3
> ORDER BY RAND()
> LIMIT 5
> ```
>
> ```
> title | news_isimage | cat_name
> :---- | -----------: | :-------
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=5ff42c053645af390254fb2c3c01a857)*